# Does Tcl have an equivalent of Perl tied hash class?

Tags: tcl, hashtable

Order of insertion is kept + search algorithm average complexity.

Comment: Do you want a tied hash (an associative array with overloaded operations) or an associative array that preserves insertion order?

Comment: Tried [dict](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm) ?

Comment: Hi ikegami. I mean an associative array that preserves insertion order. Dinesh, I know dict, but I did not see insertion order mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dict`, you can achieve this. I hope this helps.

```
% set website [dict create name stackoverflow protocol HTTP port 80]
name stackoverflow protocol HTTP port 80
% dict get $website
name stackoverflow protocol HTTP port 80
% dict get $website name
stackoverflow
%
```

Comment: What's the average-case complexity of a lookup?

Comment: Approximately constant. It's still a hash table; the order maintenance is paid for with additional space (two pointers) per element.

Comment: I do not understand. Are you saying the dict is already a tied hash?

Comment: I'm saying that dictionaries are hash tables with an order-maintenance mechanism added (I _know_ that's what they are; I wrote that code). “Tied hashes” are not a concept that is used in Tcl, at least not with that name, so I don't exactly recognise what you're asking.

Comment: A tied hash is a variable that looks like a hash, but isn't. Hash operations (fetch keys, fetch value, store value) result in methods being called on the "tied" (associated) object instead performing the usual hash operations. e.g. If `$website` was a tied hash, `dict get $website name` would call a user-defined method on the object tied to `$website`. Other languages might use polymorphism, but hashes have their own syntax in Perl. `$hash{$key} = $value;` vs `$object->method(@args);`.

Comment: @user1134991: in Tcl, only arrays have special syntax (arrays can be associated with specialized behavior, but they do not preserve insertion order). Since there is no syntactic benefit in making a `dict` call another class for behavior, you're better off just defining that class and using it, e.g. as `$website get name`, which is close enough to a `dict` invocation.

Comment: Hello Donal. This is what I was looking, but did not phrase well enough. I am an EE, not a CS major, thanks for your patience. And yes, if you wrote the code, that does give you "some authority over the matter" :-)